# How to bin data in R by the number of values and not by the numeric values?

Tags: r

I have a set of data in excel files. My data (C1 to C80) are by columns and for each data I have a different number of values. 
For example

```
C1       C2       C3    
0,5      3        80,12 
2        6,9      0,5
5,4      0,1      13 
8,7      8        20,6
(n=179)  n=(152)   n=(200)
```

I want to transform my values and bin them to have for each column the same number of rows: (n=20).

So for example if C3 has 200 values, then rows 1to10 will be in the same bin and I want the mean of the values for this bin. etc.

I tried to use the function cut and breaks but it makes bin by sorting by values, which I don't want.
What is the appropriate function to process my data ?
Thanks

Comment: By what criteria do you want you to bin the values by? What kind of transformation do you intend to apply? If you literally just want to go by row number, you can assign a grouping variable (e.g. rows 1-10 = A, rows 11-20=B, etc.) and then run your stats on that.

Comment: No matters the number of row values I have by column (and this number is different for each column), I want to transform them to have at the end 20 values for each column. The criteria is just the rank, I want to group the first ones etc. After transformation the new value will be a mean of the raw values binned together.